# How do I insert an attribute using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How do I insert an attribute using BeautifulSoup?

For example, insert `border="1"` as a `<table>` tag attribute.

EDIT:

I've answered my own question (for a particular class of table, even):

```
inTopic = urllib2.urlopen("file:///C:/test/test.html")
content = BeautifulSoup(inTopic)

tlist = content.findAll('table', "myTableClass")
for tbl in tlist:
    tbl['border'] = "1"
    print tbl.attrs
```

Comment: Post your solution as an answer and accept it then...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
inTopic = urllib2.urlopen('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951331/how-do-i-insert-an-attribute-using-beautifulsoup')
content = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(inTopic)
tlist = content.findAll('table')
for tbl in tlist:
    tbl.attrs.append(('border', 1))
```

Do not forget to try `lxml.html`, it's fast and parse well.

Answer (score 2):

with `node.attrs['myNewAttr'] = 'my_new_value'` 
for example:

```
content = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
links = content.findAll('a') 
for node in links:
    node.attrs['myNewAttr'] = 'my_new_value'
```

in this case:

```
<ul>
   <li><a>text</a</li>
   <li><a>text</a</li>
</ul>
```

will return

```
<ul>
   <li><a myNewAttr="my_new_value">text</a</li>
   <li><a myNewAttr="my_new_value">text</a</li>
</ul>
```